# Ошибка добавления элементов в список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Почему элементы дублируются в списках `a` и `b`, если добавляется только в `a`

```
a = []
b = a
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i)
print(f'{a=} {b=}')
```

Comment: вообще дубликатов огромное множество: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpython%5d%20is%3aa%20copy%20%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Python списки - это изменяемый тип данных, `а` и `b` (`a is b`) являются одним объектом:

```
if id(a) == id(b):
    print('mutable')
```

В Вашем случае лучше сделать так:

```
a = []
b = []
```

если необходимо создать поверхностную копию объекта списка:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [:] 
# ————————
b = a.copy()
```

Или с помощью библиотеки `copy`

```
import copy
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = copy.copy(a)
```

Если список `a` имеет вложенные списки:

```
import copy
a = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Списки не переприсваиваются на прямую. Нужно делать копию, чтобы на разную память ссылались.

```
a = []
b = a.copy()
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i)
print(f'{a=} {b=}')
```